# 360 image preview in Javascript (without flash)

Tags: jquery, html, image-rotation

I am looking for a way to embed a 360 modeling image on my website. Is there a way to view that on an iPhone or iPad without Flash?

Here's a generic link. http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone-3d-spin-1827.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used [jQuery reel](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel) a few times, and it's pretty good.

Here's a [demo I made](http://focalstrategy.com/tests/reel.php).

(By the way, sprites over a certain size don't work on iOS due to memory limitations, hence the distinction on my demo.)

Comment: Thanks! If only I had things more interesting than calculators to take pictures of!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to animate that with UIImageView fairly easily assuming you would be ok doing a sprite rather than an actual 3d transform.

http://appsamuck.com/day2.html

If you really want to do it in 3d you will need to use opengl you should look into unity 3d.

http://unity3d.com/unity/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple very good plugins.
Check out http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/360-view